# Lua table insert get same element

Tags: lua, lua-table

this is my code:

```
 30   for t = 1,testData:size() do
 33       -- get new sample
 34       local input = testData.data[t]
 35       if opt.type == 'double' then input = input:double()
 36       elseif opt.type == 'cuda' then input = input:cuda() end
 37       local target = testData.labels[t]
 38       -- test sample
 39       local pred = model:forward(input)
 40       test_result[t]=pred
 41       
 42       local err = criterion:forward(pred,target)
 43       te_error = te_error+err 
 44    end
 45    print(test_result[1])
 46    print(test_result[2])
```

and I get the same elements, so my table only have stored the last element, why?

Comment: What is `model:forward` returning? Is it returning a static table? I assume you are saying you get the same value for *all* entries in `test_result` and not just that those two are the same (since without knowing the data it is certainly possible for those two to legitimately be the same I would think).

Comment: HI the pred is a float vector and it did change every time, but when I insert them to table, the table contains all duplicate items

Comment: How did you test that you were getting different vectors each time? Is the vector value you are ending up with the first vector? Some random vector? The last vector?

Comment: I did print 'pred' out every step and the table ends up with many last 'pred'

Comment: Shouldn't `testData.data[t]` be `testData[t].data`?

Comment: The fact that you get a different value from it each time means it has a different value at that point. The fact that you end up with all the fields having the same (last) value at the end means you are in fact getting what I thought which is a re-used object. If you compare `test_result[1]` to `test_result[2]` I bet they compare equally (which shouldn't be true even for two vectors with the same values if they were two different tables/userdata/etc.

Comment: @EtanReisner, so if this is true, how do I solve it?

Comment: @hjpotter92, sorry for the confusion, testData:size() is overloaded in this case

Comment: You find out how to copy the object/vector and store the copy you take in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wager that the `model:forward(input)` is returning a global table. So all testResult will point to the same global table. You can check this by printing `pred` after it is received: if a global table, it will always have the same "value" (pointer). Verify that `model:forward` returns a table local to that function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703694/lua-table-insert-get-same-element#comment38315037_24703694

Comment: everytime pred is different, but after save/load they are all same

Comment: @Coderzelf Do you mean that the content of pred is different or the pred "pointer" is different. Could you update your question to show what pred looks like just after return from `model:forward` and again just after `criterion:forward`?